# How to create a custom Cast Dialog with Chromecast V3 sdk

Tags: android, chromecast

So after reading most of the V3 documentation it seems as though `MediaRouter` has become internal to the `CastContext` object and we no longer have access to it. I'm running into issues when trying to create a custom cast dialog with the V3 framework. I currently have my `MediaRouteButton` in xml and am setting it up with my activity as the context via

```
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(mActivity, mCastButton);
```

I've also tried to incorporate google's sample from 2 years ago with the V3 framework, but of course that didn't work. Here's the sample I pulled from

https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android/blob/master/src/com/example/mediarouter/MediaRouterCustomDialogActivity.java

Does anyone know of a way to make a Custom Cast Dialog from `MediaRouteActionProvider`?

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738327/how-to-make-a-custom-cast-mediarouter-dialog) if it can help you.